# Microsoft XNA code sample wont work with blender model

Tags: xna, 3d, blender, instancing

I downloaded this code sample and integrated it into my game
http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/mesh_instancing

It works with the model that they supplied, but throws and exception whenever I use one of my models.

> The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements
>   required by the current vertex shader. TextureCoordinate0 is missing.

I tried pluging my model into their original source code and same thing.
My model is an fbx from blender and has a texture.
This is the function that throws the error

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawInstancedPrimitives(
  PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
  0, 0,
  meshPart.NumVertices,
  meshPart.StartIndex, 
  meshPart.PrimitiveCount, 
  instances.Length
);
```

Comment: Does your model have textures? It says `TextureCoordinate0` is missing, that might mean that there is no texture or UV data in the model file. It is also possible that you are trying to use a file of a different version than that of what the program was designed for.

Comment: I have a Clouds style texture that blender generates. Im not useing an image based texture

Comment: I haven't done XNA in a few months but I remember having a similar issue. When you exported to fbx from blender, did you check the "Strict XNA" option? Also, try doing an unwrap on your model and then exporting. I know sometimes i had issues when it expected an unwrapped model but it didnt have the UV data

Comment: I think Mungoid is right. Make sure you have assigned UV-coordinates before exporting. You do know that your generated clouds texture will not be exported in the model, right? So you will still have to assign a texture with UV-coords if you are using a shader with texture coloring in XNA

Comment: Procedurally generated textures will not export as an image with the model by default.